# <a> href atribute to text javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

I want to ask can I with javascript and if it can how to do from the likovete href to be converted as text.?

Example

```
<a href="http://abv.bg">PAPAPA</a>

<a href="http://google.bg">Papapap</a>
```

to become only the text

```
http://abv.bg

http://google.bg`
```

It happens during the opening of the page.

Comment: so you want to grab the absolute link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith) method as follows:

```js
$("a").replaceWith(function() {
  return "<br>" + this.href;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://abv.bg">PAPAPA</a>

<a href="http://google.bg">Papapap</a>
```